# How to automatically import data into AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I know this will be very basic and possibly has been answered before but I've spent hours looking for the right resources without any luck.

I have created an RDS (MySQL) instance for our small business. We have a customer/subscription management platform and we want to keep the data from the platform on the DB.

All I could find is an API help doc: https://apidocs.chargebee.com/docs/api/exports?prod_cat_ver=1

Is this the point where I should reach out to a dev with API experience or is it something I can learn how to do myself?

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly different ways to implement this solution with AWS. For example, assume someone uploads a list with data from your platform to an Amazon S3 bucket on a daily basis and you need to automatically get this data from the list into an Amazon RDS instance.

To solve this use case, you can write a Lambda function that reads the list, connects to the RDS instance and performs a SQL Insert statement to update the RDS table with the data. Then to ensure this is done on a regular basis, you can schedule the Lambda function to run using Scheduled Events using a CRON expression.